# Get right shape of numpy array - (4112, 20, 28, 28)

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to create an numpy array that resembles = (flattened images, number of examples per class, width, height)

This is the original code:

```
train_dataset = np.zeros([no_of_classes, num_examples, img_height, img_width], dtype=np.float32)

for label, name in enumerate(train_classes):
    alphabet, character, rotation = name.split('/')
    rotation = float(rotation[3:])
    img_dir = os.path.join(root_dir, 'data', alphabet, character)
    img_files = sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(img_dir, '*.png')))


    for index, img_file in enumerate(img_files):
        values = 1. - np.array(Image.open(img_file).rotate(rotation).resize((img_width, img_height)), np.float32, copy=False)
        train_dataset[label, index] = values

train_dataset.shape


(4112, 20, 28, 28)
```

I wish to achieve the same result(the shape, not the numbers per se) with 2 examples per class, given that i have 5 classes.

I've tried:

```
data = [np.zeros((2000)), np.zeros((1)), np.zeros((40)), np.zeros((50))]

test = [np.array(x).flatten() for x in a]
test1 = np.array(test)
test1.shape


(5, 2000)
```

How can i do that?